# TriState Checkbox - how to change the order of the states

Tags: wpf, checkbox

I have a CheckBox in my application that is using the TriState mode.  The normal behavior for this mode seems to be cycling between null, false, true.

I'd like to change this behavior so that it cycles between null, true, false.

What's the best way to do this?

I've tried adding a click handler similar to this:

```
void cb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((CheckBox)e.Source).IsChecked.HasValue == false)
    {
        ((CheckBox)e.Source).IsChecked = true;
        return;
    }

    if (((CheckBox)e.Source).IsChecked == true)
    {
        ((CheckBox)e.Source).IsChecked = false;
        return;
    }

    if (((CheckBox)e.Source).IsChecked == false)
    {
        ((CheckBox)e.Source).IsChecked = null;
        return;
    }

}
```

But this seems to disable the checkbox entirely.  I'm pretty sure I'm missing something that should be obvious.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I guess the event handler and the default behavior are just cancelling each other's effects, so the checkbox seems disabled...

Actually I recently had to do the same thing. I had to inherit from `CheckBox` and override `OnToggle` :

```
public class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
{


    public bool InvertCheckStateOrder
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(InvertCheckStateOrderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InvertCheckStateOrderProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for InvertCheckStateOrder.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InvertCheckStateOrderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("InvertCheckStateOrder", typeof(bool), typeof(MyCheckBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    protected override void OnToggle()
    {
        if (this.InvertCheckStateOrder)
        {
            if (this.IsChecked == true)
            {
                this.IsChecked = false;
            }
            else if (this.IsChecked == false)
            {
                this.IsChecked = this.IsThreeState ? null : (bool?)true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnToggle();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only for completeness here additionally the solution for Windows-Forms. We have to override the `OnClick` method, overriding `OnStateChanged` results in display bug (and stackoverflow if done incorrectly).

```
/// <summary>
/// A <see cref="System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox"/> with the ability to reverse the checkstate order.
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox" />
public class CheckBoxReversible : CheckBox
{
    private bool FInvertCheckStateOrder;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether to invert the check state order from [Indeterminate->Unchecked->Checked] to [Indeterminate->Checked->Unchecked].
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///   <c>true</c> to invert the check state order; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool InvertCheckStateOrder
    {
        get { return FInvertCheckStateOrder; }
        set { FInvertCheckStateOrder = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Löst das <see cref="E:System.Windows.Forms.Control.Click" />-Ereignis aus.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Eine Instanz der <see cref="T:System.EventArgs" />-Klasse, die die Ereignisdaten enthält.</param>
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.InvertCheckStateOrder)
        {
            if (this.CheckState == CheckState.Indeterminate)
                this.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
            else
                if (this.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
                    this.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
                else
                    if (this.CheckState == CheckState.Unchecked)
                        this.CheckState = this.ThreeState ? CheckState.Indeterminate : CheckState.Checked;
        }
        else
            base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accepted solution is the best, but if you don't want to create a subclass, just do something as:

```
void chkbokHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  CheckBox senderChk = sender as CheckBox;
  bool bCheck = false;
  //here, the status is already changed, so rechange:
  if (senderChk.IsChecked == true) // from UNCHECKED
    bCheck = true;
  else if (senderChk.IsChecked == false) //from INDETERMINATE
    bCheck = true;
  else //from CHECKED
    bCheck = false;

  senderChk.IsChecked = bCheck;
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

It create the (checked) sequence: indeterminate -> true -> false -> true -> false -> true -> ...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, it has been very useful to solve a similar behavior with ToggleButton.

```
class InvertedToggleButton : ToggleButton
{
    public bool InvertCheckStateOrder
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(InvertCheckStateOrderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InvertCheckStateOrderProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for InvertCheckStateOrder.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InvertCheckStateOrderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InvertCheckStateOrder", typeof(bool), typeof(ToggleButtonInvertido), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    protected override void OnToggle()
    {
        if (this.InvertCheckStateOrder)
        {
            if (this.IsChecked == true)
            {
                this.IsChecked = false;
            }
            else if (this.IsChecked == false)
            {
                this.IsChecked = this.IsThreeState ? null : (bool?)true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!this.IsChecked.HasValue)
                this.IsChecked = true;
            else
                base.OnToggle();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, there is no `CheckBox.OnToggle()` to override in WinForms, so in that case `CheckBox.OnClick()` is where to head for.

Here's a minimal implementation of a WinForms checkbox that cycles Unchecked -> Indeterminate -> Checked -> Unchecked..., instead of the default Unchecked -> Checked -> Indeterminate -> Unchecked...

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        switch(this.CheckState)
        {
            case CheckState.Indeterminate:
                this.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                break;
            case CheckState.Checked:
                this.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
                break;
            case CheckState.Unchecked:
                this.CheckState = this.ThreeState ? CheckState.Indeterminate : CheckState.Checked;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ApplicationException("Unexpected CheckState: " + this.CheckState.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you are happy about introducing a dependency on what int values Windows assigns to what states of CheckState, this works also:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckState newState = this.CheckState - 1;
        if (newState < 0) 
        {
            newState = this.ThreeState ? CheckState.Indeterminate : CheckState.Checked;
        }
        this.CheckState = newState;
    }
}
```