# Change sequence of states on a three-state ToggleButton

Tags: togglebutton

It seems that the out-of-box sequence for a three-state ToggleButton is On, Indeterminate, Off.

I would like to change this to On, Off, Indeterminate; similar to the question presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343866/tristate-checkbox-how-to-change-the-order-of-the-states) .

I've tried modifying my StateChanging event, but I think that will result in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I briefly implemented a working solution using ToggleStateChanging to change the order of the states, and then using a global variable to avoid an infinite loop.  However, I then had a new problem where the ToggleButton had some sort of auto-theme where it was shaded differently for each state and on MouseHover.  I didn't want that theme, so I ultimately just changed the buttons to standard buttons, and now I'm using the buttons' Tag property to emulate ToggleState.

My particular solution uses a Telerik RadButton, but this would work for a standard button as well on a WinForm.

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadButton myButton = (RadButton)sender;

    switch (myButton.Tag.ToString())
    {
        case "Indeterminant":
            myButton.Tag = "On";
            break;
        case "On":
            myButton.Tag = "Off";
            break;
        case "Off":
            myButton.Tag = "Indeterminant";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```