# Indeterminate state of check box

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I have a check box in WPF and I want to set it to the indeterminate state. How can I do that? Is there a way to set it like :

```
CheckBox.State=CheckBoxStates.TriState;
```

Or is there some other way to do that?

Also is it possible to change the visual look of the checkbox as :

- ☑ for checked
- ☒ for unchecked
- ☐ for indeterminate state 
  or I will have to create a custom control?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343866/tristate-checkbox-how-to-change-the-order-of-the-states

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah... you can use a `Nullable<bool>`. Assuming you can override the Control somehow. But for a tri-state, I think the following should provide a good idea:

```
bool? = false 
bool? = true
bool? = null
```

So try:   `bool? TriState`

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  IsThreeState = true;  See following (with examples)

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-checkbox-control/

Comment: links are good. but you have to post the actual answer based on your link. that link can go dead in a couple of months and the reference won't be available to others.